# Getting value of spefic node from pattern html

Tags: html, url, curl

I want to get all names from my html page with pattern.

See below:

```
  <li >
    <span class="industry-rank">1</span>
      <span class="line">
      <span class="info">
        <a class="img-link" href="/nike/14e00e3f0bb79e4500c88440a6451b8f6cbaec5e">
          <span class="img"
                style="background-image: url(https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_13460080_75sq_1366391176.jpg)">
          </span>
        </a>
        <span class="name">
          <a href="/nike/14e00e3f0bb79e4500c88440a6451b8f6cbaec5e">Nike</a>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </li>
 <li >
    <span class="industry-rank">1</span>
      <span class="line">
      <span class="info">
        <a class="img-link" href="/nike/14e00e3f0bb79e4500c88440a6451b8f6cbaec5e">
          <span class="img"
                style="background-image: url(https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_13460080_75sq_1366391176.jpg)">
          </span>
        </a>
        <span class="name">
          <a href="/nike/14e00e3f0bb79e4500c88440a6451b8f6cbaec5e">Roger</a>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </li>
```

HTML page has urls in a repetitive manner. I want to get all names only like "nike" or "roger".

What should I do to get it?

I tried using curl to call url, but what should I do after I do that?

Comment: Can you post more HTML?  And highlight exactly which pieces you are trying to extract.  and What is your current idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in using cURL. After you create a GET request through the URL, find a library on Github to help with HTML parsing.

Here is a link to a library that will do all of the above: https://github.com/mahadazad/page-scraper